# Navigation Arrows to Silent Move - Fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I have had issues that im not good enough to resolve when using fade effect for slides and parallax for sections. so have removed fade effect and now using silentMoveto instead.

I am try to get it so when you click the navigation arrows for slides, they also use the silentmoveto.

The script below is trying to do this by using the class of the fp-controlarrow, but not sure how to get it to go to target the previous or next slide.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fp-controlArrow', function(){
    $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('3', 3);
});
```

Comment: I guees disable the default buttons. Create my own in fixed position, then use moveSlideUp, moveSlideDown. Is absolute position allowed if using vertclealignc

Comment: is there a way to get the custom buttons to stay 50% of fpviewing area, because when the scrolloverflow is on they of course center with the height of the page instead of the slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the CSS transition property. (assuming you are using `css3:true`, which is the default in fullpage.js)

```
.fp-slidesContainer{
   transition-duration:0ms !important;
}
```

[Demo online](https://jsfiddle.net/5yLsdwmt/17/)